# Regex unapply in for comprehension with if guard not compiling

Tags: scala

Why is that the following will not compile

```
for {
    s <- List.empty[String]
    regex <- List.empty[scala.util.matching.Regex]
    regex(ss) = s
    if ss == "foo"
} yield s
```

But removing the `if`

```
for {
    s <- List.empty[String]
    regex <- List.empty[scala.util.matching.Regex]
    regex(ss) = s
} yield s
```

or rearranging the order of the two lists in the for comprehension

```
for {
    regex <- List.empty[scala.util.matching.Regex]
    s <- List.empty[String]
    regex(ss) = s
    if ss == "foo"
} yield s
```

compiles?

Scalafiddle: http://scalafiddle.net/console/2519ff98d434cb522589f54a9c5fcf55

Answer (score 2):

You can see the translated for-comprehension using this command:

```
scalac -Xprint:all <file>.scala
```

In your first example the resulting code looks like this (I cleaned up the output a bit):

```scala
List.empty[String]
  .flatMap(((s) =>
    List.empty[scala.util.matching.Regex]
      .map(regex => {
        private[this] val x$2 =
        s match {
          case (x$1@regex((ss@_))) => scala.Tuple2(x$1, ss)
        };
        val x$1 = x$2._1;
        val ss = x$2._2;
        scala.Tuple2(regex, x$1)
      }).withFilter((x$3 => x$3 match {
      case scala.Tuple2((regex@_), regex((ss@_))) => ss.$eq$eq("foo")
    })).map(((x$4) => x$4 match {
      case scala.Tuple2((regex@_), regex((ss@_))) => s
    })))
  )
```

The problem seems to be that the `withFilter` clause uses the expression `regex(ss)` directly in the `case` statement, but the value `regex` it is not defined there. I'm not sure if this can be considered a flaw in the language specification, or in the compiler. The error message is certainly not very helpful.

You can read up on the details in chapter 6.19 of the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: Can you explain why rearranging the 2 comprehensions make it compile? Also is this a bug? It is not obvious according to the specification that my first one would not compile but rearranging would make it compile..

Comment: Without trying it out, I assume that rearranging the comprehensions like in your 3rd example places the `regex` value in the scope that is available to the `withFilter` clause. I can't tell if this is a bug, or if your example doesn't conform to the language specification. Maybe you could try to compile the snippet with dotty and see if you get a better error message?

Answer (score -2):

This might help you.

```
 import scala.util.matching.Regex
 import scala.util.control.Exception._



for {
    s <- List.empty[String]
    regex <- List.empty[scala.util.matching.Regex]
    ss <- extract(regex, s)
    if ss == "foo"
  } yield s



def extract(regex: Regex, s: String): Option[String] = allCatch.opt {
    val regex(ss) = s
    ss
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this help explain why one format compiles while a very similar format fails?